# wordpress - display an ACF field in the post page

Tags: php, wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I am loading a **field** in the header of my wordpress website. This field is displaying a text on top.

```
<?php the_field('text_on_top'); ?>
```

Every page display it, the name of the field is exactly the same on every ACF page. 
My problem : the **blog / post** page doesn't load that field. What is going wrong ?

Comment: Probably blog / post call a different header

Comment: This depends on your theme - but as @Nozifel points out, you probably have a different header that loads for the blog post page.  In your theme files, is there a file named `header-[something].php`? Be sure you get all the files named `header-[something].php`

Comment: In the theme I develop -so far- there is only one header.php (and no header name like this `header-[something].php` ... Should I build a new one for the blog page ?

Comment: try to use  <?php echo get_field( "text_on_top" ); ?>

Comment: It does load the right header, I checked.

Comment: Could u share ur theme tree.

Answer (score 0):

> use :  the_field() to get_field() ;

```
<?php echo get_field( "text_on_top" ); ?>
```

**Get a value from a specific post**

```
$value = get_field( "text_on_top", $post->ID);
```

[More details](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Comment: try using post id. but define more info about field.

Comment: Ok, gonna try. It's a basic text field, not a WYSIWYG

Comment: when I place  `<?php $value = get_field( "text_on_top", $post->172); ?>` I have a blank page, mistake ? (I took the ID of the field)

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake.  `$post->ID` is what you need to use (you cannot put a number in the place of `ID`).